# Use the Euclidean algorithm to prove that gcd(na, nb) = n gcd(a, b).

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Assume that a,b,n are all natural numbers.

I was going to set it up as:

na = q(1)*n(b) + r(1)     where a>b

and go down the chain:

nb = q2 * r(1) + (r2)

but something seems off. Someone told me that in the first part, it should be n*r(1), but I don't understand why. May I please have some direction?

Comment: The remainders when you run the Euclidean algorithm on $(na, nb)$ are each $n$ times the remainders that you get at the same stage when you run the algorithm on $(a,b)$. So when the algorithm terminates, the last non-zero remainder, which is $\gcd(na,nb)$ is $n$ times the last non-zero remainder when the algorithm runs starting with $(a,b)$.

Comment: Can you write this out?

Would it be:
na = q(1)*nb + nr(1)
nb= q2(nr1) + nr(2)

and I keep going? then what?

Comment: It comes down to $x=qy +r$ if and only if $nx=q(ny)+nr$.

Comment: where did the variables x and y come from? shouldn't they be using some sort of subscript.

Comment: The point is that no matter what $x$ is and no matter what $y$ is, $x=qy+r$ if and only if $nx=qny+nr$. Abstraction --- source of the power of mathematics.

Comment: Yes, if we are running EA starting with input $(a,b)$, we have at a certain stage $a_i=q_i a_{i+1} +a_{i+2}$, then at the corresponding stage starting with $(na,nb)$ we have $na_i=q_i(na_{i+1})+na_{i+2}$. But expressing using subscripts may hide the simplicity of the idea. Run EA on $(44,16)$ and $132,48)$ and you will see what's going on.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with this *Down with subscripts!* trend ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $a,b,n$ are natural numbers:

Let $d=\gcd(a,b)$; so $d|a$, $d|b$, and use the Euclidean algorithm to find integers $s,t$ such that $d=sa+tb$.

Then $\frac{na}{nd}=\frac ad$ and $\frac{nb}{nd}=\frac bd$ are integers, i.e., $nd|na$ and $nd|nb$, and also $nd=nsa+ntb$, so $\gcd(na,nb)=nd=n\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: but how is this using Euclid's algorithm?

Answer (score 3):

@bof is right, but to show that gcd$(na,nb)=nd$, in addition to $nd|na$ and $nd|nb$, you must also include that any integer $e$ such that $e|na$ and $e|nb$ implies that $e$ also divides $nd$. And because $e|(na)s$ and $e|(nb)t$, and $nd=nsa+ntb$, then $e|nd$.