# Show that for a and b non-zero integers and c different from zero, then gcd(ca,bc) = |c|gcd(a,b)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I did:

$$ca = cb * k + r \Leftrightarrow \\
ca - cb*k = r \\
c(a-bk)=r \\
a-bk = r/c \\
a = bk +r/c$$

So, $gcd(a,b) = r/c$

What do I do next?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1437530/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3430009/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/982040/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/705862/42969

Comment: You asked the same question before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3430009/42969

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**:

It suffices to show that $|c|\gcd(a,b)$ divides $ca$ and $cb$

and any number that divides $ca$ and $cb$ divides $|c|\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: And how do you do that?

Comment: Well, $\gcd(a,b)$ divides $a$ and $b$, and $|c|$ divides $c$, so $|c|\gcd(a,b)$ divides $ca$ and $cb$; on the other hand, if $d=k|c|\gcd(a,b)$ divides $ca$ and $cb$, then $k\gcd(a,b)$ divides $a$ and $b$ and hence $gcd(a,b)$ so $k$ divides $1$